# I want to add new rows to my dataset based on a condition in stata

Tags: stata, expand

This is how my data set looks:
[image: dataset]

This is what I want to do:
[image: wanted]

I am unable to do it using the `expand` command or `fillin`.

I need to do this in Stata.

Comment: So, I want to add observations to my data in such a way that in every village, all streets should have a jati corresponding to them if that jati exists in that village

Comment: Screenshots of what you have and what you want from Excel have only indirect relation with Stata. Would you post Stata stuff in a question about Excel? Please read the Stata tag wiki for advice on giving Stata examples and post the Stata code you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to `reshape` to wide format and back to long format to create observations for each street/name combination.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input byte(village streetid) str8 name byte freq
1 1 "John"     1
1 2 "John"     1
1 3 "John"     1
1 4 "John"     1
1 1 "Aisha"    1
1 2 "Anya"     1
2 1 "Jennifer" 1
2 2 "Jennifer" 1
2 3 "Jennifer" 1
2 2 "Monica"   1
2 3 "Phoebe"   1
2 4 "Phoebe"   1
2 5 "Jennifer" 1
end

// to wide format
reshape wide freq, i(village name) j(streetid)

// replace missing freq values with 0, but only if that streetid exists in the village
foreach var of varlist freq* {
    bysort village (`var') : replace `var' = 0 if missing(`var') & !missing(`var'[1])
}

// back to long format
reshape long

// drop if streetid doesn't exist in village
drop if missing(freq)

// See the results
list, sepby(village name)
```

Result:

```
. list, sepby(village name)

     +--------------------------------------+
     | village       name   streetid   freq |
     |--------------------------------------|
  1. |       1      Aisha          1      1 |
  2. |       1      Aisha          2      0 |
  3. |       1      Aisha          3      0 |
  4. |       1      Aisha          4      0 |
     |--------------------------------------|
  5. |       1       Anya          1      0 |
  6. |       1       Anya          2      1 |
  7. |       1       Anya          3      0 |
  8. |       1       Anya          4      0 |
     |--------------------------------------|
  9. |       1       John          1      1 |
 10. |       1       John          2      1 |
 11. |       1       John          3      1 |
 12. |       1       John          4      1 |
     |--------------------------------------|
 13. |       2   Jennifer          1      1 |
 14. |       2   Jennifer          2      1 |
 15. |       2   Jennifer          3      1 |
 16. |       2   Jennifer          4      0 |
 17. |       2   Jennifer          5      1 |
     |--------------------------------------|
 18. |       2     Monica          1      0 |
 19. |       2     Monica          2      1 |
 20. |       2     Monica          3      0 |
 21. |       2     Monica          4      0 |
 22. |       2     Monica          5      0 |
     |--------------------------------------|
 23. |       2     Phoebe          1      0 |
 24. |       2     Phoebe          2      0 |
 25. |       2     Phoebe          3      1 |
 26. |       2     Phoebe          4      1 |
 27. |       2     Phoebe          5      0 |
     +--------------------------------------+
```